# How to grow all fonts in an MS Word document by 0.5, not by 1?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I have MS Word 2007 and a document written with various fonts between size 8 and 11. If I select the entire text and then in Home->Font I press Grow Font the size of the characters will range from 9 to 12.

I would like to make those characters ranging from 8.5 to 11.5, this is to increase the font size by 0.5, not 1. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

There is not a way built-in to Word allowing half-point increases in all fonts in a document.

If the document is tagged with styles, you can edit the styles for that document to increase each styled block of text to a desired size. This is not going to be as simple as a relative size increase button, but on a longer or more complex document it should allow for a consistent sizing of all fonts relatively easily.

It's been a while since I've worked in Office 2007, but you should be able to right-click on each Style and select Modify, and then change the font sizes therein.